# Firefox version for selenium-firefox-driver 2.41.0

Tags: firefox, selenium

I am using the version 2.41.0 of selenium-firefox-driver in my pom xml. What version of fierfox browser has the best compatibilty with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Selenium 2.41.0 supports FF 28 and 27 and ESR 17 and 24.**

Support for Firefox is the latest release, the previous release, the latest ESR release and the previous ESR release.

For example Selenium 2.40.0 (released on Feb 19, 2014) supports Firefox 27, 26, 24, 17

Selenium with Firefox can be run on any platform that Firefox supports for those versions, that also allow users to install a custom Firefox extension.

Reference: [Platform Supported by selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp)

Answer (score 4):

> Please check all Firefox versions and its suitable drivers here:
>
> ## https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG
>
> http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG