# Firefox WebDriver doesn't work with Firefox 32

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've just updated to Firefox 32, when I attempt to run my Selenium Webdriver Test, Im getting the following

```
Failed to start up socket within 45000 ms. Attempted to connect to the
following addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055 OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException
was unhandled by user code   HResult=-2146233088   Message=Failed to
start up socket within 45000 ms. Attempted to connect to the following
addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055   Source=WebDriver   StackTrace:
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverServer.ConnectToBrowser(TimeSpan
timeToWait)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverServer.Start()
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverCommandExecutor.Execute(Command
commandToExecute)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities
desiredCapabilities)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor
commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxBinary binary, FirefoxProfile profile, ICapabilities capabilities, TimeSpan
commandTimeout)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxBinary binary, FirefoxProfile profile, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxBinary binary, FirefoxProfile profile)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor()
       at SMT.Web.FunctionalTests.Drivers.Driver.GetWebDriver(Int32 browser, String page)
```

I was expecting to be able to run the tests as per normal.

Has anyone experiencing the same thing? How did you resolve the issue?

Selenium version: 2.41.0 (Installed as a Nuget Package)
OS: Windows 7
Browser: Firefox
Browser version: 32

Comment: How do you start your tests? Show the actual code please.

Comment: Hi Alecxe, No the tests don't start only the browser starts up, the code is fine as I was running the tests this morning the only thing that had changed was the upgrade to the browser

Comment: I had the same bug this morning after upgrading firefox. I just downgraded the firefox version and it worked well. Not the best option, but is the faster one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The latest Firefox version that [Selenium 2.41.0 officially supports](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp) is **28**. Downgrade your browser. According to the other answers, downgrading to Firefox 31 is enough to make it work.

It is always a good idea to have the latest [selenium package](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) installed. The strategy, though, is always the same - make sure that you are using the version supported by your selenium package browser.

See also:

- [Firefox version for selenium-firefox-driver 2.41.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906817)
- [Unable to obtain stable Firefox connection in 60 seconds (Windows 8 + FF 32.0)](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7642)

Comment: You can find older versions here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox

Comment: See Mite's answer below, Firefox 32 is now supported by Selenium 2.43.0

Comment: It may be "supported", but it's still not working.  I'm now getting tons of "Unable to scroll element into view" errors, even with the element right there on the screen, clickable and everything.  I still can't run any tests with the latest Selenium and Firefox 32.  What a mess.

Comment: @TimHardy are you sure your issue is Firefox version related? See if your problem can be elaborated into a separate question. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

That is correct.  2.42.0, and 2.42.2 will not work with FF 32.
The failures is as follows:
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms 
.

So the strategy is to roll back until 2.43 is released.

Comment: This was fixed for me using the combination of Selenium 2.42.2 and Firefox 31.0.  See the Mozilla page on downgrading Firefox: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox

Comment: how to downgrade firefox to 28 version from 32. Please help me

Answer (score 8):

They have just released 2.43.0 (2014-09-09)

- Make sure UnhandledAlertErrors includes the alert text if provided by the driver.
- Firefox

  - Make sure the browser process is properly killed if silent startup hangs (#7392)
  - native events support for Firefox 24, 31 and 32
- Loosen websocket dependency to ~> 1.0
- Add support for `switch_to.parent_frame` (thanks abotalov)
- Fix download location for Selenium::Server.{latest,get} (#7049 - thanks marekj)

Ruby
https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/rb/CHANGES

Java 
https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG

Comment: It is not released yet for NodeJs. they kept on 2.42.1 :-(

Answer (score 3):

They have a ticket about this issue and they've fixed it for version 2.43

[see here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7642)

I don't know when they'll release 2.43, so I guess downgrade your browser or switch to HtmlUnitDriver, ChromeDriver, or OperaDriver in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downgrading your browser as others have suggested, why not upgrade your WebDriver to 2.42?

Comment: And 2.42 doesn't support 32nd version too (haven't downvoted).

Comment: I don't like upgrading gems unless there is a really good reason to do so. It causes cascades of updates, and invariably something breaks. Sometimes there is a change which requires a lot of work to fix.

Comment: WebDriver 2.43.1 supports up to Firefox 32.0.1. Just fixed it after Firefox automatically updated to 32.0.1.

Comment: Upgrading worked for me!
In order to use Firefox Webdriver in a JMeter test and get it to work with current Firefox v38 (as of may 2015) I upgraded the selenium api .jar and selenium firefox .jar both from version 2.44 to 2.45 (delete old ones and put the new ones in JMeters /lib folder. I downloaded the .jar files from the [selenium Maven site/repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver).

Answer (score 1):

Just downgraded my browser to version 31. selenium-2.42.2 does not work on FF version 32.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the latest client jar. And all  `ALL OF THEM` to the build path
there will be 2 jar files in the root, and numerous in the lib subfolder.

Download the client : http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/selenium-java-2.43.1.zip

[image]

source:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Edit:
Better solution if you use Maven. https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html
In eclipse just create new maven project, or on exists project configure -> convert to maven project.

Then insert the pom the selenium dependency. 
[selenium maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java)
Current selenium pom:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Firefox WebDriver (Selenium 2.44) now works with Firefox 32. However if you're downloading Selenium via Nuget within Visual Studio, ensure that you've got the correct project selected within the package manager console. I downloaded the new compatible version into my solution and still experienced the 45000ms timeout error. It turned out that I had updated Selenium in my main project but not in my test project.