# Firefox Selenium (Java)does not work

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am using selenium java 2.42 and mozilla fire fox-32.0.2 version,When I run the script on eclipse to launch the google it gives me error

```
 org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException:
 Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. 
 Firefox console output: 6.
```

I tried downgrading the firefox version too, but the error persists.

Comment: Seems to be compatibilty issue. You shlold downgrade firefox. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646639/firefox-webdriver-doesnt-work-with-firefox-32

Comment: Selenium latest version support firefox version till 33.0 only. so check your firefox version please.

Answer (score 0):

FF v32 is only compatible with Selenium 2.43.0+

FF versions and Selenium versions are tightly coupled.

This said, the error you are getting is not what I would expect. Is the server at 127.0.0.1:7055 up?

Comment: to what version should I downgrade my FF?

Comment: try FF v28. the version of FF supported with each selenium release is usually included in the selenium CHANGELOG - https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/CHANGELOG

Answer (score 0):

Update your selenium with latest version 2.43.0+. 
Because Firefox driver version is not compatible with older version of selenium.