# Firefox fails to load with webdriver

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

Details:

Firefox version: 31.1.1 ESR
Selenium Version: 2.43
Python Version: 2.7.8

Here is the sequence of commands I am using:

```
    from selenium import webdriver

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

This is the error I see:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 185, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
    File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    ....
   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'Session not found: ae328361-423b-4b4b-b4f3-9d3acdfa8a81' ; Stacktrace:
```

I am doing something obviously wrong but can't seem to figure it out. I have googled this error and cleared the cache in my browser, removed all the cookies. nothing seems to work. Any help with be much appreciated.

Comment: Selenium does not currently support Firefox above version 27. Revert your firefox down to 27 and it should work. http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp . Though I have found it FF28 works still.

Comment: The link you provided says "Support for Firefox is the latest release, the previous release, the latest ESR release and the previous ESR release.". I am using Selenium 2.43 and it should support Firefox version 31.

Comment: Interesting. Firefox 32 broke my code. I suppose I didn't have to revert as far back.

Comment: The comment by Mite Mitreski on this discussion of FF 32 might interest you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646639/firefox-webdriver-doesnt-work-with-firefox-32

Answer (score 0):

Just install Selenium IDE in firefox addons. And restart the browser. It should work. I faced the same error and it worked. Make sure that you are using firefox version 44 or below. and turn off it's automatic updates.

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide a path for Firefox

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox(path to firefox.exe)
browser.get('www.google.com')
....
```

Comment: Actually my code launches the Firefox browser. The error comes when it tries to open the URL.