# Unable to run selenium webdriver program in Firefox browser version 38

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm unable to run selenium webdriver scrips in Firefox version 38. Same script it will work on low versions of firefox. How to fix it.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646639/firefox-webdriver-doesnt-work-with-firefox-32. There is huge gap between firefoxdriver compatibility with latest versions.

Comment: Issue being fixed now. Updated the new version of Java jar files. Now it's working on new updated Firefox version 38.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium webdriver 2.45 will not support Firefox 38. You have to roll back your Firefox version (i.e. Firefox 37).

Wait for new client release of web driver, that will defiantly support Firefox 38.
(http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Comment: Updated the new version of Java jar files. Now it's working on new updated Firefox version 38